# special character removal 'sed'

Tags: unix, sed

I'm facing an issue where I'm getting some special characters in my file at the beggining; a snap of the same below:

```
^@<9b>200931350515,test1,910,420032400825443
^@<9a>200931350515,test1,910,420032400825443
^@<9d>200931746996,test2,910,420031390086807
```

I'm using the following command to remove anything other than numbers in first column:

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*//g' file.dat
```

No success on that. The file is created btw during a fastexport from Teradata, the process adds some special characters by itself during extract.

Any idea on the command?

Comment: does it add always the same amount of characters per line?

Comment: also it would be good to get hex output for the above lines (e.g. using `xxd`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove any non-ASCII characters anywhere in a line, you can use `tr`.

```
tr -d '\000\200-\377' <file >file.new
```

Answer (score 1):

Using perl

```
perl -lne 'print /\d+,.*/g'

200931350515,test1,910,420032400825443
200931350515,test1,910,420032400825443
200931746996,test2,910,420031390086807
```

matches only digits up to the first comma and then everything else.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is to big gun for such a small problem, 
use `cut` to remove the beginning of each line:

```
cut -b 2- file.dat
```

Where `2-` is the range of bytes you want to retain, I'm not sure how many such strange characters you have there, so I would experiment with `1-`, `2-`, `3-`, `4-`, `5-`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @krzyk. I should've mentioned the file that's created is huge (>500GBs). Also the number of characters that are added isn't constant. Some lines have 4, some 6, some 3 only. 
So, cut isn't a better option here; it's also not feasible for huge files.

Even sed takes time in such huge files. For ex: it took 4 hours on a 439GB file, same type of operation.

Comment: `cut` is faster than `sed` for such cases, but yeah, not when the number of characters is variable (generally if you have larger files you want to avoid regexes when not needed). Other good option is `tr` answer by triplee

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the number of characters that should be removed is constant across all line. To remove a fixed number of characters from the beginning of each line, you could simply do

```
$ sed 's/^.....//' input >output
```

Adjust the number of dots to fit your need.

Comment: I would appreciate a comment with the down vote.  The characters are in the beginning of each line, and seems to be the same on each line.  The `sed` script in my answer will remove characters from the start of each line. Is there an issue with this?

Comment: My apologies, I should've mentioned some more records with variable length of special characters. 
For constant length, it works. Thanks!